# iPhone maps help needed

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I saw a application (myhomes.com) for iPhones. They are using map in which markers are there when you click on marker one button is displayed (that is really a thought for me how to display a button in Objective C when we click on marker in webview because there we might using JavaScript).

That will redirect to other screen which displays details of that event. I want to use that kind of functionality in my code. they might be using some api. I am very eager to know how they are doing that. Right now I am displaying map with Google Maps / JavaScript and displaying pop of when we click on marker, but that pop up is non clickable as it is of html type.

How can I put a button on my uiview at the same position where my marker is ? How to combine Objective C with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the MapKit component documentation included with the iPhone 3.0 SDK.